# My App is Crashing while using google maps in my flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Here is the error while crashing:-

```
Process: com.example.basic_setup, PID: 13613
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at java.nio.ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.put(ByteBufferAsIntBuffer.java:122)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.n.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223017097@22.30.17 (190400-0):2)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.buffer.n.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223017097@22.30.17 (190400-0):3)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.d.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223017097@22.30.17 (190400-0):2)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.ao.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223017097@22.30.17 (190400-0):12)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bz.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223017097@22.30.17 (190400-0):29)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223017097@22.30.17 (190400-0):151)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.av.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@223017097@22.30.17 (190400-0):48)
```

I am getting error while navigating fastly from another screen to map screen in bottom navigation bar.

Comment: what do you mean by fastly ? be clear

Comment: Means when I am navigating quick from another screen tab to map screen tab

Comment: use supportMapFragment instead of Mapview. hope it will Resolve your issue

Comment: if  it resolve your issue just accept the answer

Comment: @NeelMoradiya did you find a solution? I am facing this now.

Answer (score 0):

this is the known issue in map v2:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829536

Use SupportMapFragment in xml file instead of mapview. eg :

```
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

for more infmormation follow these links :

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map

Comment: Can you please tell me where can I find this XML file because my application is in flutter...

Comment: Sorry for I didn't mention that I am developing application in flutter application

Comment: for flutter didn't have any idea.Sorry :)